# Image Allowdrop, change to dropped picture and save link

Tags: c#, image, xaml

I have this in Xaml

```
<Image AllowDrop="True" Source="{Binding InsertPicture, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Now I want that when i drop a picture on it that the actual picture changes to the picture i dropped and that i can save the link where the dropped picture is located. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your XAML code like this:

```
<Image Name="myImage" AllowDrop="True" Drop="Image_Drop_1" Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource}"/>
```

And create `ImageSourceModel.cs` class:

```
public class ImageSourceModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string _imageSource;
    public string ImageSource
    {
        get { return _imageSource; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _imageSource)
                return;

            _imageSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ImageSource");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And add this code to .cs file:

```
private void Image_Drop_1(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] fileSource= (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        Uri imageUri = new Uri(fileSource[0], UriKind.Absolute);
        myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(imageUri);
        String url = imageUri.AbsolutePath;
        ImageSourceModel _image = new ImageSourceModel
        {
            ImageSource = url
        };
        this.DataContext = _image;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. imgBear.Source is the x:name of the image in xaml. But what is filex?

Comment: Sorry, i made changes but forget some variable names. I edited my answer, so you can use it.

Comment: That works, thanks. But now I want it to save the image url EG: c:/Images/x.png

Comment: I edited again. Your image source will save in `url`.

Comment: is it possible to bind the url in xaml?

Comment: When you coded `myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(imageUri);` line, you already binded url to image.

Comment: Yes but i want to save the url in a database, so I have problems getting it into my viewmodel now